# Linking two dashboards based on a table selection in Qlikview

Tags: qlikview

In the past, I have used Tableau, another Data Visualization tool just like Qlikview where I could link a selection on a table or graph (or really an worksheet on a dashboard) to another dashboard by setting a source and destination dashboard/sheet. I did this using 'Action Filters'.

I am trying to do the same thing in Qlikview where I want to link two dashboards and transfer the selection in the source dashboard as a filter to the destination dashboard. Any idea if this is possible? And if yes, how can I implement this?

Comment: Tableau worksheets are roughly equivalent to individual chart objects in Qlikview... As long as your chart objects are in the same state, your selections should be carrying through automatically. When you say "dashboard" in Qlikview, do you really mean two separate dashboards?

Comment: Are you talking about differend QlikView documents or about different tabs in one QlikView  document?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a trigger, say, on a button which opens a new QlikView Document, there are options to transfer state. This will carry over your current selection criteria. However, the fields in the destination document must have the same name.

See button properties -> Actions -> Add -> Action type external: Open QlikView Document. You will return to the Actions tab with options available to the newly added action.

Answer (score 1):

Try to solve it with the data-model behind these two dashboard. If they use the same data resp. the data-tables are connected this works out of the box in QlikView because of the so called associative data-model in QlikView.

No need to connect the dashboards manually, zero configuration ...